# How to push an html element with display property of table-cell to the right?

Tags: html, css

So here it is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/myxgy7xg/3/
I want to push '.toTheRight' to the right of the row with a fixed width of 200px. and meanwhile the element in the middle '.b' takes up all of the rest width of the current row.

Here is the code:
html:

```
<div class="a">
    haha
</div>

<div class="b">
    classb
</div>

<div class="toTheRight">
    to the right!!!
</div>
```

css:

```
.a,.b,.toTheRight{
    display:table-cell;
}
.a{
    width:200px;
}
.b{
    width:30%;}
.c{ 
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/myxgy7xg/4/

I simply set min-width property to a and c

```
.a,.b,.toTheRight{
    display:table-cell;
}
.a{
    width:200px;
    min-width:200px;
}
.b{
    width:70%;}
.c{ 
    width:200px;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

Which forces them to take the entire 200px;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: I like your solution but i wonder is there away to guarantee that the three table-cell element can take up the entire row (which has a dynamic width, say 70% of the section)

Comment: You cannot do that without javascript if you want to mix fixed widths and dynamic widths

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript.  Try this (tested and works):

HTML:

```
//Added a wrapper div so you can get the width

<div id="divRowStuff" style="width:100%">
    <div class="a">
        haha
    </div>

    <div id="b" class="b"> //Gave this an ID since we want to manipulate it.  You can access it by child/class selectors, but for simplicity, this illustrates what you need to do.
        classb
    </div>

    <div class="toTheRight">
        to the right!!!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
//You weren't using class "c", so I removed it for clarity:

.a,.b,.toTheRight{
    display:table-cell;
}
.a{
    width:200px;
}
.toTheRight{
    width:200px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function(){
            var divRowStuffWidth = document.getElementById("divRowStuff").offsetWidth;
            var widthToSet = divRowStuffWidth - 400;
            document.getElementById("b").style.width = widthToSet + "px";
    });

</script>
```

So, basically, we determine the width of the parent element and subtract 400, since that is the known width of the other two elements that you have.  Then, we set the width of "b" to that value, so it takes up all of the remaining space.

Comment: thanks, i am not very familiar with js. so shall i just put those code in a js document or do i need to call some functions in order to execute the js code you wrote above

Comment: you could put it in an external file and reference it as such, but it's easier to just put it anywhere inside the <body> element in your HTML.  I've edited my answer with the needed tags.